# Print, modify, print again Bash variable

Tags: bash, macos, shell, csv, printf

I am looping over a CSV file.  Each line of the file is formatted something like this (it's Open Street Maps data):

> planet_85.287_27.665_51a5fb91,AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline,{ [name] Purano
>   Bus Park-Thimi [type] route [route] microbus [ref] 10 } { [Id] 13.0
>   [Srid]      3857 [FieldsTableId]

This follows the format:

> Layer,SubClasses,ExtendedEntity,Linetype,EntityHandle,Text

I want to add a new column for `Name`.  I can find the name in a line by cutting off everything before [name] and after [.  This code successfully creates a new-line delineated file of all of the names (which I open as a CSV and then copy-paste into the original file as a new column).

```
cat /path/to/myfile.csv | while read line
    do
    if [[ ${line} == *"name"* ]]
        then
            printf "$(echo $line | LC_ALL=C sed 's/^.*name\]//g'| LC_ALL=C cut -f1 -d'[') \n"
        else
            printf "\n"
    fi
done >/path/to/newrow.csv
```

This system is clearly suboptimal - I would far prefer to print the entire final row.  But when I replace that printf line with this:

```
printf "$line,$(echo $line | LC_ALL=C sed 's/^.*name\]//g'| LC_ALL=C cut -f1 -d'[') \n"
```

It prints the line but not the name.  I've tried printing them in separate print statements, printing the line and then echoing the name, saving the name in a variable and then printing, and a number of other techniques, and each time I either a) only print the line, or b) print the name on a new line, which breaks the CSV format.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I print the full original line with the name appended as a new column at the end?

NOTE: I am running this in Terminal on macOS Sierra on a MacBook Pro 15" Retina.

Comment: FYI -- using `printf`, substitutions should only be in subsequent arguments, not the format string itself.

Comment: ...and running `sed` and `cut` once per line is very, *very* inefficient -- if you're going to do your processing on a line-by-line basis, try to use [bash-native string manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the input. I'll read some more man pages tomorrow. I took a very rigorous class on Bash and C but it was maybe 5 months ago and I haven't done any since then, so at the moment I'm totally out of practice!

Comment: BTW, `LC_ALL=C` is typically overkill. Depending on exactly what the warnings you're trying to suppress are, you could probably use `LC_CTYPE=C` or `LC_COLLATE=C` (exported just once at the top of your script, if you preferred); that way error messages and date/time formatting are still appropriate to the user's preferred language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract the name between `[name]` and `[type]`, and append as the new last CSV column. You can do that using capture groups:

```
sed -e 's/.*\[name\] \(.*\) \[type\].*/&,\1/' < input
```

Notice the `\(.*\)` in the middle. That captures the text between `[name]` and `[type]`.

In the replacement string, `&` stands for the matched string, which is the entire line, as the pattern starts and ends with `.*`.
Next the `,` is a literal comma, and `\1` stands for the content of the first capture group, the part matched within `\(...\)`.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  That said, macOS users must add the LC_ALL=C when using sed and other such tools in oder to avoid warnings.

Comment: Not necessary. It depends on your environment setup. I'm on OSX too, and I didn't need to add it, and I have `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: interesting - did you do something special to set up your machine to use a more standard SED? Or is it that I'm on Sierra, which uses a BSD version?

Comment: OSX always used BSD as far as I remember. Having those warnings is not normal, not the behavior of a standard system. There's a cause somewhere, you need to debug. superuser.com might help. Good luck!